# Dealing with namespaces in E4X

Tags: apache-flex, xml-namespaces, e4x

I'm trying to get data from a namespaced xml file in a flex app. There is a root namespace (xmlns="blah") and another namespace (xmlns:i="blah"), and I'm able to access most tags using the following:

```
var ns:Namespace = doc.namespace();
var result:XMLList = doc.ns::element;
```

However, there are several tags that are subject to change in the application, and i'd like to not hardcode them, possibly using the elements method:

```
var result:XMLList = doc.elements(configuredField);
```

Is there a way to get elements with namespaces using the elements method, or a similar way to get XML elements in flex using a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you can get nodes by using dynamic properties (**[ ]** notation).

```
var x:XML=
<root xmlns:i="testNS">
    <elem1>
        hhh
    </elem1>
    <i:elem2>
        123123
    </i:elem2>
</root>;
var elemName:String="elem2";
var ns:Namespace=x.namespace("i");
var tags:*=x.ns::[elemName]; //will contain all "elem2" tags in "i" namespace
```